# протокол SmtpClient

Tags: c#, smtp, tcp-ip, osi

С каким протоколом транспортного уровня работает класс `SmtpClient` с `udp` или `tcp` или каким то еще? И можно ли как то повлиять на выбор этого протокола?

Comment: по спецификации там tcp.  Поменять вряд ли получится (но никто не мешает написать свою реализацию на udp)

Comment: а как почту отправлять по протоколу, который допускает потерю пакетов?

Comment: @teran как в TCP, сделать переотправку, если обнаруживается недостача.

Comment: @D-side ну это понятно. но в чем смысл, если есть TCP, где это уже заложено?

Comment: @teran в TCP это заложено определенным образом, который может не устраивать.

Comment: можно локальный прокси сделать, который будет в сеть ходить по udp, а сам работать с SmtpClient по tcp